# specify number of beans in df.plot(kind='hist')

Tags: python, pandas, plot, histogram

I have a dataframe `df`

and I want to plot the histograms of grouped variables as

```
df.groupby(['Variable1', 'Variable2']).plot(kind='hist')
```

Is there a way to specify the number of bins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parameter `bins` in [`DataFrameGroupBy.hist`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.hist.html):

```
df.groupby(['Variable1', 'Variable2']).plot.hist(bins=3)
```

> **bins** : integer, default 10
>
> Number of histogram bins to be used

Comment: Hi thanks! is there a way to plot the "smaller" histogram in front? the bigger histogram hides the smaller in my case

Comment: Sorry, really hard question. I dont know, really. Maybe create new question with some sample data, I think some matplotlib guru create nice answer.